# Chrome freezes [WebPack (hot reload) and Vue Dev Tools] until clicked outside the window

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, vuejs2, google-chrome-devtools, freeze

I am still figuring out if this is a Chrome issue or a problem with my laptop.

**Setup**

- I am running Windows 10, latest Chrome.
- Quad core i7, 16Gb of ram.
- My development environment includes WebPack with hot re-load. I am developing in Vue (v2) so I installed the Vue development tools.

**Problem**

After some time Chrome will start freezing but it does register my actions.
When I click outside the window, it will process all actions (at least visually) and some times unfreeze. This happen to both the main window and developer tools (on a separate window). I should also mention that not only the page inner window freezes but also Chrome as a whole. So if I click on a tab it is still froze until I click outside, moment it will change the tab.

Basically what I am describing is that any visual update only happens once one of the windows (chrome or developer tools) is unselected from the Window environment.

**Help**

Does any one experienced something similar and what was the resolution?

May this be a hardware (GPU) issue?

This is a new computer and I am deciding if I should return base on this alone. Only thing holding me back is the fact this issue is only happening with Chrome atm.

Comment: Update if anyone wonders into this thread... It was a defect (either GPU or motherboard). I returned the computer and it was repaired.
So I would safely assume there is not a danger combination between the specs I specified.